# Afraid of memory leak when use addsubiew method in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios4

in iPhone: When I add a subview to a view, using [myview addsubview: anotherview.view ] will "my view" retain in memory which may cause a problem when adding a big number of views as subviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes addSubView retains the subViews you add, and yes if you add way too many subViews you could run into memory issues, but that is highly unlikely, if that happens you will receive the

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

Followed by the:

```
- (void)viewWillUnload
```

and then:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
```

This will unload your view, and release its subviews. However don't forget to set the additional subViews to nil on the viewDidUnload method, as that subviews are also retained by the ViewController itself, therefore they will not get released when the view unloads, unless you set them to nil here.

Comment: Can I replace this current view with another view to avoid any possible memory problem, if yes, then how can I do it ?

Comment: @Alaa Eldin What view are you referring to exactly?, you can remove subViews at anytime.

Comment: here you are what I need exactly, in the application start I create an object from a view "mainview" and add it to the window, this mainview contains a button, in this button's listener (when pressed function), I should create a new view using [mainview addsubview newview.view] method, here I want to remove the mainview and show newview instead, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

in your example, `myview` will retain `anotherview.view` (view.view?..).

However, `myview` will not be retained as long as you don't add it as a subview to another view or retain it in any other way.